# Implementation of Youla Decomposition for a square skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I am looking for a publicly-available software package (preferably in Python, but I'll take what I can get) capable of performing a decomposition of a real $n\times n$ skew-symmetric (sometimes called anti-symmetric) matrix $\textbf{A} = - \textbf{A}^T$. I have seen this decomposition referred to as the Youla decomposition, for example, in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory). I don't want to assume that this terminology is well-known, so I will describe the decomposition here.

The decomposition consists in finding an orthogonal matrix $\textbf{Q}$ such that
$$ \textbf{A} = \textbf{Q} \Sigma \textbf{Q}^T \,,$$

and $\Sigma$ is of the form:
\begin{equation}\Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{matrix}
0 & \lambda_1\\ -\lambda_1 & 0\end{matrix} &  0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \begin{matrix}0 & \lambda_2\\ -\lambda_2 & 0\end{matrix} &  & 0 \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \begin{matrix}0 & \lambda_r\\ -\lambda_r & 0\end{matrix} \\
& & & & \begin{matrix}0 \\ & \ddots \\ & & 0 \end{matrix}
\end{bmatrix} \,.
\end{equation}
for real $\lambda_k$.

Comment: If nothing else, you can get this decomposition by leveraging software that does spectral decompositions or singular value decompositions

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Would this software give me this decomposition directly, or would it give me an intermediate result which I could then use to easily get the decomposition?

Comment: It would give you an intermediate result which you could use to easily get the decomposition

Comment: It seems like simply applying Schur's algorithm (e.g. in Julia or Mathematica) gives this decomposition automatically. I'm a bit surprised, because the general form of the Schur decomposition returns an upper triangular matrix, not on of this form above.

Comment: Interesting idea.  Perhaps the Julia/Mathematica Schur decomposition algorithm is set to give a [Real Schur decomposition](http://kurser.lobner.dk/LinAlg/Tilf%C2%B0jelser%20til%20Leons%20bog/RealSchur.pdf) in certain cases.  Because $A$ is normal, any unitary block upper-triangularization will yield a block diagonalization.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom any hints on how to get this decomposition from the SVD Decomposition? Where A = UDV'

Comment: @dcl we get into trouble in the case of repeated eigenvalues, but in the general (non repeating) case each pair of columns of $Q$ can be built from an associated pair of columns of $U$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Does it mean that the real Schur decomposition of a skew-symmetric real matrix is guaranteed to be in the $\Sigma$ form of the question (except for the order of the diagonal blocks)?

Comment: @Jellby Yes it does

Comment: How to go from the SVD matrix $U$ to get the $Q$?